# Android retrofit interceptor cannot chain updated Prefs value

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Here is my Interceptor, chained for all outgoing request. After "/login" request, the token is updated. I am using easyprefs for accessing sharedpreference. But the next request, updated AUTH_TOKEN value is not chained. Anybody suggest a workaround.

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {
    val token = Prefs.getString("AUTH_TOKEN", "")
    val authToken = "Bearer $token"

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Api-key", "xxx-xxx-xadxsdx-fsccsag-xxx-xx")
            .addHeader("Authorization", authToken)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably using a `Singleton` instance this is why instance variable will be initialized once. With this structure you should get preference value inside `#intercept()` so that you will get updated values each time.

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = Prefs.getString("AUTH_TOKEN", "")
        val authToken = "Bearer $token"
        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Api-key", "xxx-xxx-xadxsdx-fsccsag-xxx-xx")
            .addHeader("Authorization", authToken)
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the auth token after it's been saved, not when instantiating the interceptor:

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = Prefs.getString("AUTH_TOKEN", "")
        val authToken = "Bearer $token"

        val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Api-key", "xxx-xxx-xadxsdx-fsccsag-xxx-xx")
            .apply {
                if (!token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    addHeader("Authorization", authToken)
                }
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
}
```